# Need ability to exit Alt key underline mode, possibly with ESC key

Tags: wpf, keyboard-shortcuts

**Question**: How do you exit keyboard hot-key mode after pressing and releasing the Alt key?  In Office the `ESC` works, in WPF it does not.

**Details:** I have various `Label` elements in a WPF application.

```
<StackPanel>
    <Label Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="_Textbox 1" Target="textbox1" />
    <TextBox x:Name="textbox1" Width="50" />
    <Label Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="T_extbox 2" Target="textbox2" />
    <TextBox x:Name="textbox2" Width="50" />
</StackPanel>
```

When I press and release the `Alt` key the `P` stays underlined and I can then separately press the `P` key and that Label takes its action.  This is the same as how Word 2013 and Notepad work in that you don't have to press the `Alt` and the `P` at the same time.

Where WPF differs is I cannot press the `ESC` key to stop the underlining and stop the auto-navigation to `Label` controls.  The only way I see to get out of keyboard navigation mode is to use the mouse and click somewhere, defeating the goal of keyboard navigation.

Comment: Actually there is a slight difference in Notepad and Word 2013 behavior. The control's there with the hot-key are in a `Menu` which takes Focus as soon as you press Alt and you can see they get focus cos the text area caret goes missing and `Esc` then returns focus to the `TextBox` while clearing the "_". Now in your sample code if you  put the two `Label`'s or even one inside a `<Menu></Menu>` and then press Alt, you get the same behavior as Word or Notepad. Without the Menu there is no control that wants to take the intermediate focus.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to my original comment

> Actually there is a slight difference in Notepad and Word 2013 behavior. The control's there with the hot-key are in a Menu which takes Focus as soon as you press Alt and you can see they get focus cos the text area caret goes missing and Esc then returns focus to the TextBox while clearing the "_". Now in your sample code if you put the two Label's or even one inside a  and then press Alt, you get the same behavior as Word or Notepad. Without the Menu there is no control that wants to take the intermediate focus.

This just seems to be an issue where the `Menu` gets a deferred focus to handle these hotkeys in it's own [FocusManager.IsFocusScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.focusmanager.isfocusscope.aspx).

Another snippet from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.focusmanager.aspx?PHPSESSID=tn8k5...):

> The following scenario illustrates how keyboard focus and logical focus change in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) application that has a Window with a TextBox and a Menu which has a MenuItem. When keyboard focus changes from the TextBox to the MenuItem, the TextBox losses keyboard focus but retains logical focus for the Window focus scope. The MenuItem obtains keyboard focus and obtains logical focus for the Menu focus scope. When keyboard focus returns to the root Window, the element in Window focus scope with logical focus will obtain keyboard focus, which in this case is the TextBox. The TextBox now has keyboard focus and logical focus. The MenuItem loses keyboard focus, but retains logical focus for the Menu focus scope.

**Solution:**

If you just can't stand the fact that you're limited with the grouping requirement imposed by the `Menu` to achieve the hot-key functionality, you could do something like:

```
<Grid Margin="25">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="15" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <!-- cannot use Visibility="Collapsed" or "Hidden" on the Menu to make it take focus on Alt press --> 
  <Menu Width="0"
        Height="0">
    <Label x:Name="label1"
            Content="_Textbox 1"
            Target="{Binding ElementName=textbox1}" />
    <Label x:Name="label2"
            Content="T_extbox 2"
            Target="{Binding ElementName=textbox2}" />
    <Label x:Name="label3"
            Content="Another Loose Label to Link Text_Box 1"
            Target="{Binding ElementName=textbox1}" />
  </Menu>
  <Label Grid.Row="0"
          Grid.Column="0"
          Content="{Binding ElementName=label1,
                            Path=Content}" />
  <TextBox x:Name="textbox1"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            Margin="15 0 0 0"
            VerticalAlignment="Center" />
  <Label Grid.Row="2"
          Grid.Column="0"
          Content="{Binding ElementName=label2,
                            Path=Content}" />
  <TextBox x:Name="textbox2"
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            Margin="15 0 0 0"
            VerticalAlignment="Center" />
  <Rectangle Grid.Row="3"
              Grid.RowSpan="2"
              Grid.Column="1"
              Margin="10"
              Fill="Tomato" />
  <Label Grid.Row="4"
          Grid.Column="2"
          Content="{Binding ElementName=label3,
                            Path=Content}" />
</Grid>
```

So in this setup we do not use any custom `Style`'s for any of the control's. We pretty much create a new top level `Menu` and add all the desired hot-key `Label`'s to it and set it's Width and Height to 0.

Thus in the actual Visible `Grid` layout we can position the visible `Label`'s anywhere we choose and to avoid code duplication in specifying the `Label.Content` twice for each `Label`(Once in the Menu and next in actual layout) we use a Binding to get the Content for the Visual Label from it's corresponding Label in the Menu.

**Update**

Reply to OP's comment:

> I'm not sure this will be practical in my application. I have hotkeys all over the app with some being duplicates inter-screen. It wouldn't be maintainable to implement this type of workaround.

Well I don't see how duplicates or having stuff all over makes any difference to this tbh.

- If you have duplicate hot-key's in multiple `Window`'s, then define `Content` for these duplicate item's as a `String` resource in xaml or your .resx you can refer to it everywhere you need it.
- Maintainable - Well you do not have anything you do special for maintainability. Your layout is not impacted, your not restricted with anything. If anything you got one `<Menu>` sitting hidden at the Top level of each of your `Window`'s that defines the hot-keys for that `Window` and within that Window any control that wants that functionality Binds to the corresponding Menu child item. I think it unifies the scope of hot-keys in a `Window` to a single place than in multiple different places.

Finally, I ain't trying to impose this approach on you, it's boils down to your personal preference. If your uncomfortable with it then you could get your `Label`'s sub-classed and implement the functionality of deferred focus yourself or raise a Microsoft bug to see if they can maybe address it for you or find an alternate solution or let go of the hot-key functionality all-together.

Comment: You are definitely onto something here.  The glitch with this code is the keyboard shortcut only works for the first Label defined in the XAML. If you reverse the order of the Labels the second shortcut starts working. Great effort on this!

Comment: @KevinKalitowski oh yh I've missed that bit indeed. The issue is when Alt is pressed the first declared `Menu` gets a deferred focus and thus only HotKey's in that `Menu`'s children respond. In the original Style each `Label` got wrapped in an individual `Menu`, hence causing the issue where only one of the HotKey worked based on which label was declared first. I've tweaked the Style to be applied on the Menu instead of Label's thereby making it a requirement to add all `Label`'s as children on **one** `Menu` to thus allow both hotkey's to function. Updated my answer and seems to work fine.

Comment: @KevinKalitowski I've also added an alternate approach where we can skip defining any custom `Style`'s and use a separate Menu pretty much as a Container for all hotkey's. This approach solves the issue with requiring all hot-key Label's to reside in the same Menu as we got a separate Menu handling that requirement kept hidden visually allowing UI to be laid-out with all the freedom you need.

Comment: I'm not sure this will be practical in my application.  I have hotkeys all over the app with some being duplicates inter-screen.  It wouldn't be maintainable to implement this type of workaround.

Comment: @KevinKalitowski I added my reply to your comment as an update to the answer cos it just won't fit in a comment.